# How to store Java Callable job in ConcurrentHashMap

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrenthashmap, callable

I am new to the Multithreading and here is a question:
For a Callable interface, like:

```
public interface Callable<V> {
    public V call();
}
```

Now I need to implement a class with three method:

```
/* register some callable jobs with the signal key */
void register(int signal, Callable cb); 

/* unregister */
void unregister(int signal, Callable cb);

/* run all the jobs with the given signal */
void signal(int signal);
```

I am thinking the register and unregister function I will use a ConcurrentHashMap in java, some structure like :

```
ConcurrentHashMap<Integer, List<Callable>>
```

Then here are my questions:

1. how to support the above three method? How to pass a Callable as a variable? The void signal(int signal) will run all the callable with the given signal key.
2. for Callable interface, need to implement the V call() function. How does this call() relate to the signal() method? Should signal call this call()?

Comment: This question is too board. You need post more details. Such as is it ok to add Callable when executing tasks? What do you expect when signal while there is another signal running?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create new iterface extends callable and add your custom method like getId.

```
 public interface  MyCallable  extends Callable<String> {
  public int getId();
}
```

-Create a implemented class which will implement your custom callable interface.

```
 public class CallableImpl implements Callable<String> {
       private Callable action;
       private int key;
     public CallableImpl (Callable action,int key){
          this.action=action;
          this.key=key;
        }
        @Override
        public String call() throws Exception {
          return  action.call();
        }
    public int getId(){
     return key;
}
```

-register(int signal, Callable cb) method will take the object of callable class and store in a hashmap.On call to void signal(int signal) it will collect all list of action from hashmap and submit to an executor.

```
ExecutorService executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(10);
void signal(int signal){
for(Callable c:actionList){
  //submit Callable tasks to be executed by thread pool
  Future<String> future = executor.submit(callable);
  //add Future to the list, we can get return value using Future
  list.add(future);
}
}
```

Comment: Thanks gati. Learned a lot from your post. One question: if another thread is calling signal, will it be a better idea to use concurrentHashMap? Will ConcurrentHashMap solve the concurrent signal() situation?

Comment: If multiple thread simultaneously operating single map ,it is always better to use cocurrent hashmap.But in your case using a list which is it self mutable.So you have to handle the scenario while updating list.

Comment: I see your point! Thanks again @gati sahu. I just did some research and seems that 1. CopyOnWriteArrayList; 2. create list as vector by need to synchonized when traversal the vector; 3. use Java8 List.forEach.

Comment: if you like the post please click on up-vote .One more point while using you need to consider read/write ratio .For an example CopyOnWriteArrayList will create for update.So better use less write more read